# PHP: generate datePeriod and match dates quickly

Tags: php, sum, intervals, date-range

I'm generating a daterange array with the following method: ($from and $to are given)

```
$begin = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $from));
$end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', $to));
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$range = new DatePeriod($begin, $dateInterval, $end);

foreach ($range as $date) {
    $dateIntervalArray[$date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')] = array();
}
```

Next, I add data from a MySQL query and match them with the interval-array (here for hourly aggregation, however) (This takes the most of the overall time)

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $dateIntervalArray[date('Y-m-d\TH:00:s', $item->PointOfTime - 900)][] = $item->measurement;
}
```

In the last step I aggregate the data:

```
foreach ($dateIntervalArray as $key => $item) {
    $arraySum = array_sum($item);
    array_push($energyData, array(
        'PointOfTime' => strtotime($key),
        'ValueHT' => $arraySum
    ));

    // Further, I calculate e.g. min/max 
    // find min per hour

    // find max per hour

    // Sum per hour

    // Total sum

    // Total average
}
```

**This works fine!** However it is slow with a bigger amount of data. I got 96 sets of per day, which are nearly 35000 data per year. If I fetch even more data, like it is normally the case I'm dealing with, I'm handling nearly 350.000 data. Takes ~6-7 seconds to render in my web frontend.

**Q: How could I improve this?**

I thought about calculation this by MySQL, however I need the maximum value per hour, even if I sum by day or month. Ideas?